# AWS Python boto3 Chatbot service available?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, chatbot

I am looking at the documentation of AWS Python boto3 SDK. I don't see anything for Chatbot service. Is it under a different name?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html

Comment: I would say that is because the chatbot is not actually a service. It is a plugin for slack or chime. Do you have any API reference that boto should implement / does the chatbot even have a regular AWS api? I do not think so.

Comment: I looked up it is called as Lex

Comment: That may be what is underneath chatbot but chatbot itself still does not have an API. Check slack and chime instead of boto.